# Exception handling required from eclipse even if it had worked without?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, user-interface

I am writting a basic gui with some buttons, and my instance of my guimain class is called guimain.

I have imported this project to another computer and after this change eclispe crys that:
unhandeled exception surround with:

```
try {
maingui.showStart();
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried to clean the project, but I even get this mistake at my old laptop. Therefore I am looking for a solution to prove maingui for exceptions, so that I do not have to worry everytime I use it.

[image: This is what it looks like right now]

I appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: Could you provide the source for `maingui.showStart()`?

Comment: In particular, what is the signature of `maingui.showStart()`. Does it declare any exceptions in a `throws` clause?

Comment: p.s. It looks like you tried to add a screen shot of your IDE, but I can only see the scroll bars. Typically such screen shots are less than helpful, especially if you are trying to show us code or error messages. You can (and should) simply copy and paste this information into your question, rather than giving us a screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java requires that if its possible your method raises a checked exception you

1. either declare the method to throw the exception
   or
2. handle the exception in your method.

This doesn't sound like an eclipse issue, but rather a java compiler telling you you have to surrond with a try catch (2 above) or update your method declaration to throw the exception (1 above)

Comment: Note that this is only true for checked exceptions. Subclasses of `RuntimeException` are considered unchecked and don't require either of these.

Comment: very true, but from the sounds of the original post eclipse wasn't building so i thought this was the compiler complaining about an uncaught checked exception.

Comment: Good point. I took the liberty to add a one word clarificationto your answer ;-)